# Reduce line length for function input python

Tags: python-3.x

My current line length is too long:

```
if the_client.mismatched['NextGenName'] != the_client.mismatched['XfinName'] and the_client.mismatched['XfinName'] != None:
```

Is it possible to make this into multiple lines?

Comment: `x='XfinName';c=the_client.mismatched;if c[x] and c['NextGenName']!=c[x]:`

Comment: Do you want to ***Reduce line length*** or divide it ***into multiple lines*** ? What's your main goal?

Comment: im just trying to fix my pylint warning about the line length. There has to be a better way than creating more objects in memory.

Comment: Add repeated code to `vars`, just like my comment above, or take  advantage of functions, which will significantly reduce your code size, apart from that, I don't see any other big *improvements* that you can make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put line breaks in an expression grouped by parenthesis

```
if (the_client.mismatched['NextGenName'] != the_client.mismatched['XfinName']
    and the_client.mismatched['XfinName'] != None):
    pass
```